# Why do I get tree conflicts between identical files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I have my trunk, and I have a branch: toast. I've made changes to the toast branch and want to merge them back into trunk. This has been done many times before and I didn't expect to encounter any problems.

I have a directory of images that haven't been altered at all, nor has the path to the directory. **Can someone please explain to me why I would get a tree conflict for every image in the directory?**

Comment: Do you work with any other developer who may have made changes to your repository? http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Comment: No, it's just me on this project.

Comment: Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951078/tortoise-svn-tree-conflict-with-myself. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inspect logs of trunk and branch file(s) in order to find source of problem.

In common "tree conflict" in SVN means "merged sources was moved|renamed on one side and edited on another in parallel" and **no any other reasons**!!!

Comment: I didn't ever really find a fix - I just resolved all conflicts with the (much more up to date) branch.

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten tree conflicts on files when I have a branch that I've kept up-to-date from trunk, and then merged that branch back into trunk.

These conflicts look like this:

```
C   path/to/some/file.ext
>   local add, incoming add upon merge
C   path/to/some/other/file.ext
>   local delete, incoming delete upon merge
```

So it's always the same exact change (verified by inspecting the diff), but seems that SVN is not smart enough to know that the remote change (from the branch) came from the local change (trunk) as I was keeping the branch updated.

When I know this to be the case, I just resolve them all:

```
$ svn resolve --accept working -R .
```

Note: svn version 1.7.19